# Import Cookies from Google Chrome Mobile to another Mobile browser

Tags: browser, chrome-for-android, cookies

I would like to know that is there anyway I can import cookies from Android version of Google Chrome to any other mobile browser (on the same device)? 
Just like when we install Firefox/Opera/Chrome on PC, they ask you to import cookies and stuff from other browsers.

Answer (score 1):

No; apps on Android do not have access to each other's data/files unless they are stored in a common external location, which cookies are not.

It might be possible to do this as root but I would suspect that they are using different formats/layouts.